# Defining a clicked button

Tags: java, android

I have 9 buttons.
Each is collored to either `red`, `blue` or `green`.
The user has to click a green box and then the game gives him a point.
So in order to check if the box is colored green, I need to define it, get the color from it and compare it to the color the user has to pick, but I have a problem.

The problem is with defining the clicked button in order to use it to `getColor()`

I can make 9 functions, first defining first button, second defining second button etc.

But is there any faster way to do it?

Can I do something like

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.THIS_CURRENT_BUTTON);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Because an onClick listener gets passed into it the view that was clicked, you can make just one onClick listener and assign it to all of the buttons:

```
View.OnClickListener listenerToCheckColor = new View.OnClickListener () {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button button = (Button)v;
        if (((ColorDrawable)button.getBackground()).getColor() == yourGreenColor)
        {
            // + 1 point
        }
    }
});
```

You can see from this line `Button b = (Button)v;`, the view that was pressed is cast to a Button, leaving you with a button the same way that `Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.THIS_CURRENT_BUTTON);` would.

After creating the listener, it needs to be assigned to each button:

```
for(Button button : myArrayOfButtons){
    button.setOnClickListener(listenerToCheckColor);
}
```

Comment: Hmm but the listener is never used, tried the code but it doesnt work, yes I have changed to my greencolor

Comment: @KamilCiesielski After creating the listener, you must also assign it to each of your buttons: button.setOnClickListener(listener);

Comment: God BLESS, now I know that OnClickListener always does code to the exact thing that is in the code, not the whole application, definitely will come in handy, with your help I finished my game.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `View.setTag()` or `android:tag` in xml. When set button green color, you set green tag by code `btn.setTag("green");`. If you want to know what color the button is, you can know by code below:

```
String tag = (String) btn.getTag();
if ("green".equals(tag)) {
    //button is green
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need separate 9 functions. You can have one function to check which colored button is clicked.

**XML Layout:**

Add `android:onClick="btnPressed"` to **all your buttons** like below

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="btnPressed"
    android:text="Button"
    android:background="@color/green"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
```

**Colors XML:**

Create your color in resource XML like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="green">#008000</color>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
</resources>
```

MainActivity Java file:
Create `btnPressed` method and check which colored button is clicked

```
public void btnPressed(View view) {

    int colorId = ((ColorDrawable) view.getBackground()).getColor();
    int greenColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.green);

    if (greenColor == colorId) {
        // Green colored button is clicked
        // Do your code here
    } else {
        // Other colored button clicked
    }

}
```

Hope this will be helpful!

Comment: Did you check my answer?